# When is a question considered duplicate?

Tags: discussion

Given the interactions I had with the mods on this [question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/282772/82408), maybe this is very obvious to the more experienced, but I would appreciate some clarifications on what's considered a duplicate.

Several links were provided as having answered the same question. However, I don't entirely agree. Those questions asked about what is the most appropriate way to seal AC line penetrations and they all suggested duct seal (or in one case, also a specialized flashing). When polyurethane spray foam was mentioned, it was discouraged because spray foam is messy and difficult to remove later on.

My question was, for the purpose of waterproofing, "whether spray foam is appropriate or fundamentally problematic and would always be leaky". I don't think any of the linked questions addressed this aspect at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mere fact that spray foam doesn't appear in any of those answers as a viable solution strongly implies that it's inappropriate. They also don't specifically say that cotton balls are inappropriate, but we can once again *infer* that they're not a good solution.

There are also many questions on this site discussion spray foam as an exterior solution in general, which would have been a better question in your case--it's not terribly important that you're sealing HVAC lines in particular.

Unfortunately my time and the number of formal duplicates both have limits. Stack Overflow allows multiple duplicate links, which can later be modified for improvement. DIY does not.

*Correction: Multiple linked duplicates has recently been enabled on this SE network. I just noticed today.*

Comment: Please do not take what I'm saying next as an endless attempt to reopen the question, as I've already accepted an answer. A hypothetical purely for clarifying the reasoning: Epoxy is not mentioned in any of those answers, but if it is used (for some unfathomable reasons), then it would be an acceptable material with good waterproofing properties. With this information, one can decide not having to rip everything out, but just fill gaps with additional epoxy. That's the essence of my question and again I don't think it's answered nor really implied.

Comment: Fair enough. Agree to disagree? I did vote to reopen, though. I'm not an unreasonable person.

Comment: Thank you! I totally get the need to whip the questions on SE to standard -- that's what makes this site great (thanks to you and other mods who are volunteering time!) I did do my due diligence so very much wanted to clarify what's considered a good question.

Comment: Sure. I'm not a mod; just a user with a neatness disorder. :P